# Count Points from Images on a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I am adding images to a grid in the code below. I need to be able to say, if molePopUp is being shown on the grid add one to an integer, so I can keep score of all the times the image is correctly pressed. Any Help?

```
// Change Image from "Hut" to Mole \\
private void ChangeImage()
{
    Image molePopup = MoleImage();
    int numCol = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfColumns);
    //Random Number - Col
    Random randomColumns = new Random();
    int ranCol = randomColumns.Next(1, numCol);
    //Random Number - Row
    Random randomRow = new Random();
    int ranRow = randomRow.Next(1, NumberofRows);
    string Moleimage = TUtils.GetIniFileString(Moleini, "ImagePath", "PictureFile", Root + "mole2.png");
    //Populate Grid with Mole at Random Times \\
    Grid.SetRow(molePopup, ranRow);
    Grid.SetColumn(molePopup, ranCol);
    grid_Main.Children.Add(molePopup);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just increment your count in your `ChangeImage` method. I am a little unsure as to what you actually need help with. There is nothing in this code handling clicks or anything like that.

Comment: @pstrjds I am making a whack a mole game, and when the mole is being shown, (molePopUp), and it is clicked when it is still being shown, I need t add that to the score.

Comment: Then you need to add a click handler for the grid cells. When the cell is clicked, check if the mole is shown, if it is than increment your count.

Comment: I know, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

handle the MouseUp event directly on your mole image. add this somewhere in your ChangeImage Method:

```
molePopup.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler((o, e) => 
{
    // check here with "e" if the left button has been pressed
});
```

Better: Create a new ControlTemplate for System.Windows.Constrols.Button in a xaml ResourceDictionary which simulates the look of the Image Control (rectangular, no round corners). You also can add Triggers to get some visual effects on mouse over and click.

Create a new Instance of the Button Control in your ChangeImage Method and assign the ControlTemplate.
Now capture the Click event with `.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(...)` instead.

Comment: Thank You, I have been working on this problem for such a long time!